# Fetch Node data from drupal into CiviCRM

Tags: drupal, custom-fields, ajax, jquery

I am interested to know if it is possible to fetch node data from Drupal into CiviCRM.

Is there anyway to do this?

My End Goal is to to populate a "select list" with node titles from drupal and depending on which title you choose, fields values will change.

Thanks,

Moe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to figure this out so data is Fetched directly into CiviCRM. However, I ended up using Drupal EntityQuery and fetched the data into a webform then Used Javascript PopUp Feature and parsed the data back into the CiviCRM form using Jquery.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

On which forms do you wish to add the fields/logic?

I feel like there are two questions here:

1) How to build an arbitrary list of options from a third-party source of data (Drupal)

2) How to set the value of one field based on the value of another fields.

For (1), arbitrary lists, you can look into [hook_civicrm_fieldOptions](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_fieldOptions/), which can dynamically modify the option list for any field. I believe the value still needs to be valid, but if it's a select that stores an integer or a string, I think it's OK.

For (2), I have an extension called [fieldconditions](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/fieldconditions/tree/master), but it is not end-user oriented because it requires writing custom javascript (I would be happy to improve it, if anyone is interested).

Alternatively, CMS-specific form builders (Caldera for WordPress, Webform for Drupal7) might be able to help, until [formbuilder](https://civicrm.org/blog/colemanw/building-form-builder) is ready (also known as [afform](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/afform)).

Comment: Note that I have my own extension [fieldlookup](https://github.com/MegaphoneJon/fieldlookup) that does the same thing as fieldconditions.  It doesn't require writing generic JavaScript, but doesn't have a UI yet.  At some point we'll have to join these two extensions together...

Comment: @JonG-MegaphoneTech - How does your extension work without a UI? How do i assign the fields.

Comment: @Moe - you know what, I haven't yet added the callback function feature yet, so mine may not be ready for you.  Using `hook-civicrm_fieldOptions` is a good choice though.  I actually thought I had an example for you, but it uses a deprecated earlier version of that hook.